# Is there an easy way to measure the FPS of my Mac app?

Tags: macos, performance, cocoa, profiling, instruments

I'm working on a Mac app, and one of the NSTableViews seems to have a little lag when I scroll it, but I'm not sure if I'm just imagining it.

The [Instruments manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringGraphicsPerformance.html) has a section on how to measure the frame rate of an iOS app, but when I try it for my Cocoa app, Instruments.app says "This instrument does not support the macOS platform".

Is there any (relatively easy) way to measure the FPS of my table view when scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is Quartz Debug. 
Go to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/, download Additional Tools for Xcode.

After you open Quartz Debug, Command + 3 will reveal a frame meter.